# onclick event listener not functioning?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

I don't know (pure) JS very well and I have one problem - I added event listener for links with class `insideLink`, but it isn't working, can you explain me why?

```
<a href="post/view/3" class="insideLink btn btn-info">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment">
   </span>{{storyCommentsBtn}}
</a>
```

```
function MyApp()
{
    this.addEventListeners = function()
    {
        var links = document.getElementsByClassName('insideLink');

        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        {
            var element = links[i];
            element.onclick = function(event)
            {
                event = event || window.event
                event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue=false);

                console.log('Clicked');
            }
        }
    }
}

app = new MyApp();
app.addEventListeners();
```

Comment: [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/o5q0yhsd/) works, I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing against?  I'm aware that I.E. doesn't support at least one type of event listener ("server side events"); maybe there are others it also doesn't support?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o5q0yhsd/1/ its working

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim, Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Just moved link from href to data-href (e.preventDefault() don't work correctly):

```
<a href="#" data-href="post/view/3" class="insideLink btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>{{storyCommentsBtn}}</a>
```